# how can I declare java interface field that implement class should refine that field

Tags: java, interface

How can I declare java interface field that implement class should refine that field ?

for example

```
public interface IWorkflow{
    public static final String EXAMPLE;// interface field 
    public void reject();
}

// and implement class
public class AbstWorkflow implements IWorkflow
{
    public static final String EXAMPLE = "ABCD"; /*MUST HAVE*/
    public void reject(){}
...
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See section 9.3 of [the specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/download/langspec-3.0.pdf).  There is no overriding of fields in interfaces - they are just hidden in some contexts, and ambiguous in others.  I'd just stay away.  Instead put a getter in the interface (getEXAMPLE())

Comment: Is is it just me. Doesn't serializable do this?

Comment: @GlenLamb - either I'm not following where you're going, or perhaps you misread the question?

Comment: Whenever you implement Serializable i'm told that I need to declare a SerializableUID or something. Isn't that what the question is trying to achieve?

Comment: @GlenLamb - Ah, I see.  That's a very specific compiler feature - there's nothing, in Serializable.java that drives the warning behavior, which is what nguyên was after.

Comment: AH, yes that's also what I was after but figured you could do it because of that. Damn. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

You can't.

Also, an `interface` can't require `static` methods to be defined on an implementation either.

The best you can do is this:

```
public interface SomeInterface {
    public String getExample();
}
```

Comment: See this post for more background information:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512877/why-cant-i-define-a-static-method-in-a-java-interface