# method overloading and primitive types

Tags: java, overriding

I have a java program that I want to discuss here and get your thoughts and opinions

```
public class StackFriends {

    public static void go(short n) {
        System.out.println("short");
    }

    public static void go(Short n) {
        System.out.println("SHORT");
    }
    public static void go(Long n) {
        System.out.println("LONG");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Short y = 6;
        int z = 7;
        go(y);
        go(z);
    }
}
```

Why do I get compile time error?

1. is it because for both go(y) and go(z) the compiler cannot decide whether to call go(Long n), go(Short n) or go(short n)?
2. is the declaration

   ```
   Short y = 6;
   ```

   valid? If it is valid, `public static void go(Short n)` -- would accept only the wrapper object of type Short?
3. Please let me know how wrapper classes behave and are the possible values they can take as arguments in this case?

I know I can do a little more research and find it all by myself, but it gets a little lonely to use the compiler all by yourself, I just want to discuss it and learn, it gives a lot of joy.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: If someone downvotes the question (and I'm not saying they will or won't), it's because it doesn't meet site standards. Don't take it personally; either correct the question or take it to a more appropriate forum.

Comment: 1. It is overriding, not over riding. 2. This is not overriding. It is overloading which is hell of a different thing :).

Comment: You don't get the desired results because you're searching about overriding but this is overloading.

Comment: Be aware that comments along the line of "please don't downvote this" are almost always on low quality posts. They make people look more closely into if the question deserves downvoted so make you more likely to be downvoted

Comment: `I know I can do a little more research and find it all by myself, but it gets a little lonely to use the compiler all by yourself`---don't take it personally,but,SO wants it's users to first concentrate and research itself and then ask questions!So,please try searching more for it by executing and searching a lot! And,lastly,I think you may receive numerous downvotes!!!

Comment: Thanks for all the answers (especially), comments and downvotes everybody. I never take downvotes personally, but it just comes along with the inconvenience of not able to participate and ask any other question using the same account.

Comment: And regarding researching, if research should be the prerequisite for asking a question here, then there would not be much questions asked here, because with time and research, any person can find answers for question. Well, that's my humble opinion

Comment: @user3790568 That's not always true. Take [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23453287/why-is-final-not-allowed-in-java-8-interface-methods) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23453568/what-is-the-reason-why-synchronized-is-not-allowed-in-java-8-interface-methods), which are questions which reasonable searches are not likely to answer. Yes, *some* research should be a prerequisite for asking, but that does not mean you should spend an infinite amount of time doing so. Sometimes it's faster to have someone give the answer, but sometimes you learn more the other way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: this answer won't cover typos in code like the missing semicolon (;) after `System.out.println("SHORT")` or similar.

> is it because for both `go(y)` and `go(z)` the compiler cannot decide whether to call go(Long n), go(Short n) or `go(short n)`?

The compiler can choose which method to use. Here's the reason:

- `short` is a primitive type.
- `Short` is a class, not a primitive type, so `short` and `Short` variables are way different and the compiler can choose which one to use.
- `Long` is a wrapper class for `long`, and a `Long` **is not** a `Short` (don't pass the is-a test) and a `short` cannot be autoboxed to `Long`.

The call to `go(z)` cannot compile since compiler cannot *shrink* the `int` variable into a `short` automatically. After that, `int` cannot be autoboxed nor to `Short` nor to `Long`, so there's no valid method that can receive an `int`. If you want to make it pass through `go(short)` you need to make a explicit cast:

```
go((short)z);
```

---

> is the declaration `Short y = 6;` valid?

N̶o̶,̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶i̶s̶n̶'̶t̶.̶ ̶A̶n̶y̶ ̶l̶i̶t̶e̶r̶a̶l̶ ̶i̶n̶t̶e̶g̶e̶r̶ ̶n̶u̶m̶e̶r̶i̶c̶ ̶v̶a̶r̶i̶a̶b̶l̶e̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶v̶e̶r̶t̶e̶d̶ ̶i̶n̶t̶o̶ ̶a̶n̶ ̶`̶i̶n̶t̶`̶ ̶v̶a̶r̶i̶a̶b̶l̶e̶.̶ ̶`̶i̶n̶t̶`̶ ̶c̶a̶n̶n̶o̶t̶ ̶b̶e̶ ̶a̶u̶t̶o̶b̶o̶x̶e̶d̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶`̶S̶h̶o̶r̶t̶`̶,̶ ̶s̶o̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶r̶a̶i̶s̶e̶s̶ ̶a̶ ̶c̶o̶m̶p̶i̶l̶e̶r̶ ̶e̶r̶r̶o̶r̶.̶ ̶T̶o̶ ̶m̶a̶k̶e̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶c̶o̶m̶p̶i̶l̶e̶,̶ ̶a̶d̶d̶ ̶a̶ ̶t̶y̶p̶e̶ ̶c̶a̶s̶t̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶`̶s̶h̶o̶r̶t̶`̶ ̶f̶i̶r̶s̶t̶:̶

Yes, it is. This is because the literal value will be automatically type casted from `int` to `short` and then autoboxed to `Short`. Also, the literal integral value `6` fits in the range of values for a `short` variable. If your literal value is outside the range, you will get a compiler error:

```
Short s1 = 6; //compiles fine
Short s2 = 32768; //compiler error
```

---

> Please let me know how wrapper classes behave and are the possible values they can take as arguments in this case?

This is very broad. Read a tutorial about it. Here are the related official tutorials:

- [Autoboxing and Unboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)
- [The Number Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberclasses.html)

Comment: I wasn't the downvote, but I want to point out that `Short y = 6;` will compile (and is not causing his compile time issue). His compile-time issues are a forgotten `;` and calling `go()` with an `int` when the method does not exist to take an `int`. He was asking why his code will not compile, these are the issues he had.

Comment: Thanks for the Wonderful answer Luggi, I appreciate your help. Your answer made my day

Comment: @Mike, missing a semi colon is pure typo - when I posted the question here

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void go(Short n)

{ 

    System.out.println("SHORT")

}
```

Should be (you forgot a semi colon)

```
public static void go(Short n)

{ 

    System.out.println("SHORT");

}
```

You also call

```
go(z);
```

With z being an int, but there is no

```
public static void go(int n)
```

Only `long`, `short`, and `Short`. I added the semi colon and changed

```
    int z = 7;
```

To

```
    Long z = 7L;
```

And it will compile for me. The above two issues were the only issues I found that would trigger compile-time issues, if you fix these, your compile time issues will be resolved.

The solution with changing the `int z` to a `long z` would be:

```
public class StackFriends {

    public static void go(short n) {
        System.out.println("short");
    }

    public static void go(Short n) {
        System.out.println("SHORT");
    }

    public static void go(Long n) {
        System.out.println("LONG");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Short y = 6;
        Long z = 7L;
        go(y);
        go(z);
    }

}
```

You could also add another `go()` function to accept an `int`

```
public static void go(int n) {
    System.out.println("INT");
}
```

With the full code being

```
public class StackFriends {

    public static void go(short n) {
        System.out.println("short");
    }

    public static void go(Short n) {
        System.out.println("SHORT");
    }

    public static void go(Long n) {
        System.out.println("LONG");
    }

    public static void go(int n) {
        System.out.println("INT");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Short y = 6;
        int z = 7;
        go(y);
        go(z);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mike, I like your answer, I would Vote up your answer if only I have 15 reputations

Comment: It's a nice debugging thing you have there, but you don't really answer OP's actual question: "Why do I get compile time error?"

Answer (score 0):

Add `;` after `print` statement of method `go(Short n)`

```
public static void go(Short n) {
    System.out.println("SHORT");
}
```

Define a method `go()` to take integer as parameter

```
public static void go(int n) {
    System.out.println("int");
}
```