# Why we cannot use synchronized keyword in an interface method declaration

Tags: java, synchronized

Can anybody explain why we cannot declare a synchronized method in an interface, by giving a real world example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is simple, a synchronized is an implementation detail and it does not belong to an interface. In an interface all the methods do not have the implementation detail.

The docs says:

> Note that a method declared in an interface must not be declared
>   strictfp or native or synchronized, or a compile-time error occurs,
>   because those keywords describe implementation properties rather than
>   interface properties. However, a method declared in an interface may
>   be implemented by a method that is declared strictfp or native or
>   synchronized in a class that implements the interface.

You may also refer: [What is the reason why “synchronized” is not allowed in Java 8 interface methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23453568/what-is-the-reason-why-synchronized-is-not-allowed-in-java-8-interface-methods)

Comment: Then, should not we put in the interface but the implementor class?