# How to bind a generic parameter to a specific List subclass?

Tags: java, generics

I would expect in the code below :

```
public static <K, D extends List<T>, T> List<Map<K, D>> meth(K k, D d) {
    List<Map<K, D>> daBytes = (List<Map<K, D>>)
            new ArrayList<Map<K, List<List<Byte>>>>();
    // ...
}
```

the compiler to figure out that `D` is a `List<List<Byte>>` and/or that `T` is a `<List<Byte>` -  and to actually get rid of the cast. Instead I get :

`Cannot cast from ArrayList<Map<K,List<List<Byte>>>> to List<Map<K,D>>`

and I need the cast anyway.
Why ? Is what I want somehow possible (without the [strategy pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18760495/281545) workaround) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`D` is specified by the *caller* of `meth`; you can't force it to be some other particular type inside `meth`.  If by `D` you mean `List<List<Byte>>`, then you should write that:

```
List<Map<K, List<List<Byte>>>> daBytes = new ArrayList<Map<K, List<List<Byte>>>>();
```

If you mean for `D` to be arbitrary, then you should be writing

```
List<Map<K, D>> daBytes = new ArrayList<Map<K, D>>();
```

Comment: I see - `D` can either be a `List<List<Byte>>` or a `List<Byte>` - see code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18749426/281545). So I know it must be a list of something - `?` is no use as it can't be manipulated and anyway I need to assign it to a specific type. Anyway I can do what I want (question 2) ?

Comment: No, you can't really do what you're trying to do like that.  You could do `ArrayList<Map<K, List<T>>`, though, but you couldn't restrict `T` to be either `Byte` or `List<Byte>`.

Comment: Apparently I wasn't the only one to think about this functionality: https://github.com/functionaljava/functionaljava/blob/master/core/src/main/java/fj/data/Either.java