# what is the implicit declaration of interface methods in Java 8?

Tags: java, methods, interface

I was reading my old SCJP 6 book(author Kathy Sierra,Bert Bates) mentioned

- All the `interface` methods are **implicitly** `public` and `abstract` by default
- `interface` methods must not be `static`

For example, if we declare

```
interface Car
{
    void bounce();               //no need of public abstract
    void setBounceFactor(int b); //no need of public abstract
}
```

What the compiler sees

```
interface Car
{
    public abstract void bounce();
    public abstract void setBounceFactor(int b);
}
```

But *from Java 8*, interfaces can now define static methods. [see this article everything-about-java-8](http://www.techempower.com/blog/2013/03/26/everything-about-java-8/)
My question, what is the implicit declaration of interface methods in Java 8? Only `public` or nothing?

Comment: My understanding is that the default `public` and `abstract` will still remain to be true.

Comment: @user2860598 : If you declare method `static` then how `abstract` can work?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/513001/2860598

Comment: Static interface methods can't be abstract, just like all the other static methods. Only instance methods are implicitely public and abstract.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rules for *implicit* modifiers do not change. Implicit modifiers are used when no other modifiers are specified. `abstract` is implied when neither `static` nor `default` has been specified. And all methods are always `public` whether implicit or explicit. Note that `interface` fields were always implicitly `public` `static`. This doesn’t change too.

But for the final words we should wait for the completion of Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

> what is the implicit declaration of interface methods in Java 8? Only
>   public or nothing?

**Answer is:** It is still `public`. `private` or `protected` are restricted. Look at following two examples

```
public interface A {

    static void foo() {// Its ok. public will implicitly call.
        System.out.println("A.foo");
    } 
   private static void foo2() {// Compile time error
        System.out.println("A.foo2");
    }
}
```

Comment: this does not answer the question... o.O

Comment: Thanks for reply. Question is not about how static methods are declared and access? I want to know *implicit declaration of interface methods in Java 8* What about abstract?

Answer (score 0):

Afaik it is something you can add and is added without changes to implementing classes.

For example. The List class will have a sort() method added. A sub class could have this method already but if every class needed this method it would break a lot of code and make having a default a bit useless.

I believe it is expected that the default method will be simple and call a static method or helper class to leave the interface uncluttered.

in short, default methods are public but not abstract.

btw interfaces have a method for static field initialisation.