# I am not reducing visibility from interface yet I get the "Cannot reduce visibility" compile error

Tags: java, interface, visibility, implements

I am working on a employee management system for training, and I made some interfaces so I can work from there.
As I was working on it, one of my methods gave me a compiler error, saying that I could not reduce visibility. But I never did.
Here is the interface and the method that gives me this problem.
Interface:

```
interface setter{
    boolean setPerformance(int id,int score);
    void setAttendance();
    boolean setNewEmployee(int id,String passWord,String name);
    boolean setRank(int id,int rank);
}
```

The class with the method :

```
class localSetter implements setter{

    localGetter get;
    browser browse;

    boolean setPerformance(int id,int score) {
        if(get.getRank(browse.returnBrowserId()) >= 1 || Integer.toString(score).length() > 2) {
            return false;
        } else {
            String oldValue = localGetter.storage.get(id);
            String newValue = oldValue.replaceFirst("Pf:\\d\\d", "Pf:"+score);
            localGetter.storage.put(id,newValue);
            return true;
        }
    }

    void setAttendance() {
        String oldValue = localGetter.storage.get(browse.returnBrowserId());
        int start = oldValue.indexOf("At:");
        String newValue = oldValue.substring(0,start + 3) + browse.currentDate() + oldValue.substring(start + 3);
        localGetter.storage.put(browse.returnBrowserId(),newValue);
    }

    boolean setNewEmployee(int id,String passWord,String name) {
        if(get.getRank(browse.returnBrowserId()) > 2) {
            String value = "Ps:"  + passWord + "Nm:" + name + "Pf:0";
            localGetter.storage.put(id, value);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    boolean setRank(int id, int rank) {
        if(localGetter.storage.isEmpty() || get.getRank(browse.returnBrowserId()) >= 3) {
            if(localGetter.storage.containsKey(id) == false) {
                return false;
            } else {
                String oldValue = localGetter.storage.get(id);
                String newValue = oldValue.replaceAll("Rk:\\d+","Rk:" + rank);
                localGetter.storage.put(id, newValue);
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

As you can see, both the interface and the implemented method has no visibility modifiers, yet it keeps telling me to add the "public" modifier.
Somebody help me please. Thanks.

Comment: The implicit access modifier in an interface is `public`. But in a class, it's package-scoped. So you're reducing. You should explicitly declare it public in the class.

Comment: This answer provides some more info about implicit modifiers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48891413/426463

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods in interfaces are implicitly `public`. In classes, if you don't specify an access modifier, the method would be accessible only by classes from the same package, thus reducing the visibility of the method.

TL;DR - a method implementing an interface's method, must be `public`.