# Can interfaces have static methods or java class stati'fy interface method?

Tags: java, static

The following is allowed:-

```
public interface JustImplementMe
{
   public void ClimbMountain();
}
```

The following is not allowed:-

```
public interface StaticMethodInterface
{
   public static void Climb();
}
```

The following is allowed:-

```
public class Classic implements JustImplementMe
{
   public void ClimbMountain()
   {

   }
}
```

The following is not allowed:-

```
 public class ClassicMusic implements JustImplementMe    
 {
      public static void ClimbMountain()
      {
        // static method cannot hide the instance method in JustImplementMe
      }  
 }
```

Why is it so? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512877/why-cant-i-define-a-static-method-in-a-java-interface

Comment: In Java 8, interfaces can have static methods

Comment: @Zeeshan that's covered in the Q/A as well