# why getBorderInsets method is not static?

Tags: java, border, insets

Why is the following method is not static?

```
public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c)
```

It returns the insets of the supplied Component. But since it is not static I need to create a border object to call this. What is the point? Am I missing something?

The way it is supposed to be used:

```
Border  b = BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder();
Inset i = b.getBoderInsets(someComponent);
```

Comment: didn't you created it probably?

Comment: @SarthakMittal Anyone who uses this method probably needs a Border object thats true but what is the point? I was following an example code and this was pretty confusing for me.

Comment: `"Why is the following method is [sic] not static?"` -- Because [you can't have static methods on an interface.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512877/why-cant-i-define-a-static-method-in-a-java-interface)

Comment: @azurefrog. Ok I didn't realize that border is an interface. That was what I was missing. Thanks