# Ensure that a static method is implemented

Tags: java, interface, static-methods

I have several Java classes which contain static methods. I want to ensure that these static methods are implemented by each of the classes. How can I enforce that, since declaring static methods is not allowed in interfaces in Java?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512877/why-cant-i-define-a-static-method-in-a-java-interface

Answer (score 2):

Sort answer: You can't enforce that.

Static methods are not inherited the same way as instance methods, so you wouldn't be able to use it for anything meaningful anyway: You can't call `MySuperClass.staticMethod()` and expect some subclass to handle the call. This means that you have to call it using `MySubClass.staticMethod()` in which case you'll get a compilation error if `MySubClass` doesn't implement `staticMethod`.

I would suggest you look into solving it using a singleton or factory pattern and use instance methods:

```
MySuperClass.getInstance(parameter).yourMethod()
```

Answer (score 2):

`static` methods are allowed on interfaces in Java8.

However, there's no way to *enforce* a class to implement a static method.

The only thing you can do, is make them non-static and `abstract` (either in an interface or in an `abstract` class).

Answer (score 2):

If you have code that calls these methods, it won't pass compilation if they are not implemented. If you don't, you don't really need them.