# Why my interface methods cannot be overridden?

Tags: java, error-handling, interface, compiler-errors

I'm trying to implement interface like this :

```
public interface Human{

    void talk();
}



public class Ame implements Human{

    public static void talk(){
        System.out.println("Speak English");
    }
}



public class Chin implements Human{

    public static void talk(){
        System.out.println("Speak Chinese");
    }
}


public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Chin c = new Chin();
        c.talk();
        Ame a = new Ame();
        a.talk();
} 
}
```

But it shows errors :
Ame and Chin talk() cannot implement Human talk().

                     Methods is overridden as static .

Please tell me why this heppened and how to fix this error.

Comment: Why are you trying to use static methods?

Comment: You cannot have a static and a non-static method of the same name and signature. And a static method does not implement the interface.

Comment: I'm just curious why Human talk() cannot be override as static talk().

Comment: More information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512877/why-cant-i-define-a-static-method-in-a-java-interface)

Answer (score 3):

`Static methods` are part of `Class` and not Objects. `Overriding` is concept of `polymorphism`, ie, a method associated with an instance can have multiple behaviour.

Static methods are not associated with instance and `polymorphism` cannot be applied.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a method as `static`, it belongs to the class as a whole and not a specific instance. The methods of an interface cannot be static in Java. When you implement an interface, you are expected to provide an instance method for the abstract methods of the interface. When you use a static method, your static method tries to hide the instance method of the same name. But this would violate the rules to be followed while implementing an interface. Thus we cannot make the interface methods as static in the implementing class.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reference a non-static interface from a static method this way. In essence, a static method is one that can be accessed directly without recreating a local duplicate object, but its values cannot be modified in the same way. Really, the solution to this problem is quite simple. **Remove the static modifier from the overriding talk() methods**