# Android Studio: breakpoint in static method of interface does not work

Tags: java, android, android-studio, breakpoints, retrolambda

Android Studio does not stop on lines in a static method of an interface.

Example: see method `getFilteredNotes` in the interface [Utils.java](https://github.com/Yarikx/reductor/blob/v0.9.3/example/src/main/java/com/yheriatovych/reductor/example/Utils.java#L30) of project Conductor (version `0.9.3`):

```
public interface Utils {
    // some lines removed for readability

    static List<Note> getFilteredNotes(AppState appState) {
        List<Note> notes = appState.notes();
        NotesFilter filter = appState.filter();
        return filter(ConsPStack.from(notes), note ->
                filter == NotesFilter.ALL
                        || filter == NotesFilter.CHECKED && note.checked
                        || filter == NotesFilter.UNCHECKED && !note.checked);
    }
```

when I convert the interface to a class, then it works:

```
public class Utils
```

Why do the breakpoints not work on the interface?

More details:

- Android Studio Version `2.2.2`
- Virtual Device: `Nexus_6_API_25.avd`

  - Android: `7.1.1`
  - CPU: `x86`
- setting `minifyEnabled=false` for the debug build did not help
- the project is using retrolambda

Comment: Interface static methods were added in Java 8. Android has been only recently added Java 8 compilation. That's just a guess, though

Comment: You can find all the answers in this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512877/why-cant-i-define-a-static-method-in-a-java-interface?rq=1

Comment: @TiborLeóSáfár I don't see what the linked answer has to do with my question. I am asking why the **breakpoints** don't work on static interface methods. Static interface methods DO of course work.