# How does Enum takes the main method in java?

Tags: java

Why is Enum allowed to have a main method?
Does it work as a normal main method?
What is the purpose of having a main in Enum?
Is main taken like a normal method?

Comment: In Java `enum` is a special form of `class`, so it may contain a `main()` method...

Comment: Similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512877/why-cant-i-define-a-static-method-in-a-java-interface

Comment: If you’re asking for a reason, it’s probably either too opinion-based or just guess-work. Neither is well suited for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `enum` is nothing more than a `final` class with a `private` constructor and a given set of instances. There's nothing special about it with regards to other methods it can contain, and a main method is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Why legislate against it ?  Because it seems "common sense" to some "majority" who look at things from an inevitably very specific perspective ?  In language design it is generally a bad idea to try and legislate "common sense" upon its users.

Comment: I asked a reason, I've studied C. A reason was all. Thank you for the enlightenment.