# Why can't I access static methods of an interface using an instance variable

Tags: java, language-lawyer

Why can't I access static methods of an interface using an instance variable.

```
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AWD a = new Car();
        a.isRearWheelDrive(); //doesn't compile
    }
}

interface AWD {
    static boolean isRearWheelDrive() {
        return false;
    }  
}

class Car implements AWD {
}
```

Comment: The only related quote I could find in the Java 8 [specifications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html) goes as follows: "An interface can declare static methods, which are invoked without reference to a particular object."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In java 8, why cannot call the interface static method that the current class is implementing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29383083/in-java-8-why-cannot-call-the-interface-static-method-that-the-current-class-is)

Comment: Why would you want to?

Answer (score 10):

### Static Interface Methods Aren't Inherited by Subclasses

You can't access static methods of interfaces through instances. You have to access them statically.  This is a bit different from classes where accessing a static method through an instance is allowed, but often flagged as a code smell; static methods should be accessed statically.

That's because static methods of classes are inherited by subclasses, but static methods of interfaces aren't.  That's stated in [§8.4.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8) of the specification:

> #### [8.4.8. Inheritance, Overriding, and Hiding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8)
>
> …
>
> A class does not inherit static methods from its superinterfaces.

When you are looking up the accessible methods for the instance, the static method from the interface isn't among them.

### Options for the code

So, as the code is now, you need to access the method statically:

```
AWD.isRearWheelDrive()
```

However, it seems like you want this to be an instance method, in which case you should probably be using a default method that returns **false**:

```
interface AWD {
  default boolean isRearWheelDrive() {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Even that seems a little bit odd, though.  It seems like you'd probably want that default method to be *overriding* some non-default method in a super-interface.  That is, you probably want something like:

```
  interface HasDriveWheels {
    boolean isRearWheelDrive();
  }

  interface AllWheelDrive extends HasDriveWheels {
    @Override
    default boolean isRearWheelDrive() {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: @JoshyaTaylor I suspect OP knows that and is asking why (which seems like a good question since the same limitation does not apply to classes). Have you found any specific statement in the Java specs illustrating this?

Comment: @Mena the reasoning is the same as for the pure existance of interfaces: If you allow access to static method in this way, you would have the diamond problem all over again.

Comment: @Turing85 I agree, but I'm just curious as per why I can't find any explicit statement in the Java specs :)

Comment: I'm still looking at the spec, but I suspect that this has to do with how the method to invoke is found.  In the past, when interfaces didn't have static methods, there would have been no language for "search the static methods of the *interfaces* of the type of the object";  adding that in would mean introducing potential future ambiguity if a static method was added to an interface.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor [here you go](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12).

Comment: @Turing85 Yup, I'm already wading through parts of that.  Haven't found the specific bit yet. I think that it's going to fall into which methods are accessible.

Comment: @Mena Turing85 linked to JLS7, not JLS8.

Comment: I think it's [8.4.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8), "a class does not inherit `static` methods from its superinterfaces."  I found that in another question that's probably not quite a dupe (it already assumes knowing the answer): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29383083/in-java-8-why-cannot-call-the-interface-static-method-that-the-current-class-is.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor kudos.

Answer (score 3):

This is specified in [The Java® Language Specification, §15.12.3. Compile-Time Step 3: Is the Chosen Method Appropriate?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.3)

> If the form is *ExpressionName* `.` *[TypeArguments]* *Identifier* or *Primary* `.` *[TypeArguments]* *Identifier*, then the compile-time declaration must not be a `static` method declared in an interface, or a compile-time error occurs.

In retrospect, the ability to invoke a `static` method through an instance is of little use, even less than the inheritance of `static` methods. I’m quite sure that a lot of developers consider it a design mistake that is only kept due to compatibility reasons.

For the newer feature of `static` methods in an interface, there was no compatibility constraint that required repeating this mistake, hence, the rules for `static` methods in interfaces were designed differently. This is also the solution with the smallest impact on compatibility with old code.